# Displaying a default value on table lookup

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables:

```
t1
 code

description_of_t1_code
 code
 description
```

If I join these tables for displaying only descriptions, it may happen, that 
there is no description for the code yet.
Is it possible to display any default description including the code, if there is no description?

e.g.:

```
t1
===
r
g
x

description_of_t1_code
======================
  r, red
  g, green

output:
=======
 red
 green
 unknown color(x)
```

Where "unknown color(x)" is the default value.

Thank you!

Comment: [left join] coalesce(..., 'unknown color(x)')?

Comment: are you having that `r,red` in one column r two different columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COALESCE will return the first non null value.
So if the description is null, use CONCAT to build a string containing the code

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.descrition, CONCAT('unknown color(', t1.code, ')'))
AS description 
FROM t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN description_of_t1_code t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
```

Answer (score 1):

`coalesce()` to replace the values

```
select coalesce(t1.descrition,'**unknown color('+t.code+') **') as description 
from t left outer join description_of_t1_code t1 on t.code= t1.code
```

Comment: is null is reported in pg as unknown function:-( The second variant after some names-fixing worked! coalesce was the keyword, thanks!

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz which database you used ?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz `isnull` is sqlserver specific function. if you using mysql then `ifnull` is the function for you

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz isnull is not supported by postgresql. i didnt knew you use this. you can use `coalesce` or simply case statement